# GCC C compiler must be 12.2.1, not compiling

Tags: movesense

I have just recieved my movesense sensor. Read the documentation, and seen movesense youtube introductions videos...

I am running the docker movesense/sensor-build-env:2.2, and have the latest git clone from git@bitbucket.org:movesense/movesense-device-lib.git.

Must be something I have missed, cause when I am building the sample code, it seems that the compiler in the build environment (in the docker as I understands it), is not matching the code or something:

-- PATH_TOOL_PYTHON will use python from shell PATH
CMake Error at /movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/app-build/compiler/gcc-version-check.cmake:2 (message):
GCC C compiler version must be 12.2.1! --- (9.2.1 detected)

Anyone that can point me in the right direction what I am doing wrong?

I tried to follow the "getting_started" example provided movesense documantation.
https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/getting_started/

Comment: The CMake caches used compiler version. So when changing a build environment, it is a good idea to create a clean build folder.

Comment: Thanks @Fleksnes, for posting it. I had same issue and from your answer, I manage to sort it out too. I could complie the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I sorted it out. After comparing my approach with the example for third time, I spottet some copy paste mistakes. In the docker start command, I had an extra "/" and was missing the last project folder. Somehow that lead to docker to start anyway, but with wrong version of compiler.