# Movesense: Running App after compiling to receive data

Tags: movesense

I am trying to run sample code of movesens from https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/src/master/samples/  After compling it on a docker container as instructed at https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw_1.9/getting_started/. Thanks to @Fleksnes to point out [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77970991/gcc-c-compiler-must-be-12-2-1-not-compiling/).
I could complie the code. However, I am having difficulties to run the app (service).

They have very poor documentation to explain it.

Now I am unable to see, how to run the app and get the data.

I tried calling executable file generated by last step : `ninja pkgs` as explained here: ([https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw_1.9/getting_started/#:~:text=The%20created%20Movesense.hex%20file%20can%20be%20found%20in%20the%20same%20directory.](https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw_1.9/getting_started/#:%7E:text=The%20created%20Movesense.hex%20file%20can%20be%20found%20in%20the%20same%20directory.))

And getting following is the issue:

```
root@e3e67ad4eb0e:/movesense/MyBuild# ./Movesense

qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped

Segmentation fault
```

I don’t know how container will have access to bluetooth port and get the data from sensor device

Can someone help with this?

I have posted same issue at https://bitbucket.org/movesense/movesense-device-lib/issues/118/running-app-after-compling

Comment: Since you transferred your question to bitbucket, you may want to remove this question from here. It's not really a kind of question that fits stackoverflow.